# Does a bigger radio room translate into higher chances for a rare or legendary dweller?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Okay, first things first: can you actually get a rare/legendary dweller from the radio room?

First I built a 2-wide radio room with high-charisma dwellers working it and average dwellers were arriving nicely enough, okay. But, if I want rare/legendary dwellers, can I expect them to show up from broadcasting?

If I build a bigger radio room, will that attract rare dwellers? (I don't really see the point in manning a larger room if all it does is tweak the timer... am I wrong?)

Answer (score 6):

From the Bethesda Blog, developers confirm that Legendary Dwellers only comes from Lunchboxes :(

http://www.bethblog.com/2015/06/30/fallout-shelter-a-legendary-dweller-from-the-commonwealth/comment-page-1/#comment-424325

Answer (score 0):

The community is fairly sure you can only get legendary dwellers from lunchboxes, but I couldn't find anything concrete, but it's extremely hard to definitely prove a negative.

Rare dwellers can come from a radio room, but the only thing a larger room contributes bringing dwellers in faster. Upgrading the room doesn't directly increase the chance of rare dwellers showing up.

Comment: A larger room also allows more people working it, for a larger happiness boost.